# How to change div fotorama__stage height on product view page

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images, product-view, fotorama-slider

How can I change height in the below code on Product detail page

```
<div class="fotorama__stage" data-fotorama-stage="fotorama__stage" style="width: 462px; height: 372px;">
```

I have tried below code in `app/design/frontend/Custom/mytheme/etc/view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
                <width>280</width>
                <height>400</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_image_large" type="image"/>
            <image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
                <width>870</width>
                <height>700</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">
                <width>870</width>
                <height>700</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image">
                <width>870</width>
                <height>700</height>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
</view>
```

It is only changing the image size and not the div size.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: Refer to this site all about gallery widget information https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_gallery.html#options

Answer (score 9):

You will have to override `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/gallery.phtml` file by putting it into `app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml` with following code change.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
        "mage/gallery/gallery": {
            "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
            ...
            ...
            ...
            "options": {
                ...,
                ...,
                ...,
                "maxheight": "350", //Change max-height that you want to set

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect answer with explanation! Made my day :) +1

Comment: @rizwan not working i have update gallery.phtml and tried with view.xml . Product images size is updated as view.xml file but <div class="fotorama__stage" data-fotorama-stage="fotorama__stage" style="width: 358px; height: 318px;">  the style wont change

Comment: I added maxwidth and maxheight to \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\GalleryOptions. https://www.magesystem.net/blog/post/how-to-change-product-image-fotorama-size.html

Answer (score 4):

in `Magento_Catalog::product/view/gallery.phtml` you can see config for gallery:

```
var config = {
        "width": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width'); ?>,
        ...
        "height": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height'); ?>
    }...
```

as you can see, `width` & `height` points to `product_page_image_medium` image size. Head over (or add id from the theme you inherit) to `YourTheme/etc/view.xml` and change

```
<image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
            <width>590</width>
            <height>800</height>
</image>
```

to your needs. Or you can just change it in config (could cause problems).

Comment: Even with these changes it won't resize the stage UNLESS you resize the `<div class="product-info-main">` and `<div class="product media">` elements in the main content area.  The stage sizes to fit the available space so the image will be floating in the middle unless you resize the columns.

Comment: You have to rebuild image library afterwards

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me, hope it will help others as well.

Place this code just after your code in `gallery.phtml` file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui'
    ],
    function(
        $
    ) {
        $(window).load(function(){
            console.log("readyyy");
            $(".fotorama__stage").height($(".fotorama__img").height());

            $( window ).resize(function() {
                console.log("resize");
              $(".fotorama__stage").height($(".fotorama__img").height());
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of late, but for future devs: you have to change this in the fotorama.js file. You can set your height modifying these values:

```
/**
         * Set height for gallery
         * Default value - height of first image
         * Number - set value in px
         * String - set value in quotes
         *
         */
        height: null,

        /**
         * Set min-height for gallery
         *
         */
        minheight: null,

        /**
         * Set max-height for gallery
         *
         */
        maxheight: null,
```

I also suggest you copy the file lib/fotorama/fotorama.js to your theme_folder/web/fotorama/fotorama.js

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Place this code just after your code in gallery.phtml file**
~

```
require(['jquery', 'mage/gallery/gallery'], function($, gallery){

    $('[data-gallery-role=gallery-laceholder]').on('gallery:loaded', function () {
        if($(window).width() > 768){
            $(this).on('fotorama:ready', function(){
                var  api = $(this).data('gallery');
                $('.fotorama__stage').css('height','500px')
                $('.fotorama__stage').css('width','500px')
            });
        }
    });
});
```

~

Answer (score 1):

**Place this script in `gallery.phtml` file just after your code in**

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'mage/gallery/gallery'], function($, gallery){
    $(document).on('click', function() {
        if (!$('body').hasClass("fotorama__fullscreen")) {
            $('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]').on('gallery:loaded', function () {
                $(this).on('fotorama:load', function(){
                   var newHeight = jQuery('.fotorama__stage__frame.fotorama__active img').prop('naturalHeight') + 'px';
                    jQuery('.fotorama__stage').css('max-height',newHeight);
                });
                $(this).on('fotorama:showend', function(){
                   var newHeight = jQuery('.fotorama__stage__frame.fotorama__active img').prop('naturalHeight') + 'px';
                    jQuery('.fotorama__stage').css('max-height',newHeight);
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above solutions but didn't work. I was able to solve this by adding the below CSS

```
.fotorama__stage {
    max-height: 80%;
}
```